# Troubleshooting Switch Mode Power Supply

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, fuses, troubleshooting

I am trying to troubleshoot switch mode power supply from HP workstation. I have done visual inspection and didnt find any anomalies on the capacitors. I reckon that the culprit might be the fuse as there is absolutely no light nor fan movement when the power supply is connected.

Before proceeding I have two questions:

1. Is it safe to permanently remove heat shrink (without replacing)
   on various components?
2. Is the location of the fuse is in the area
   circled yellow in the image?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and no. The circled component isn’t a fuse, it’s a line filter and it is at line potential so needs the heat shrink around it to protect the rest of the system.

The fuse is somewhere else.

Comment: And if the fuse is blown, there's a reason for that - something else is broken and must be fixed, otherwise the new fuse will blow immediately.

Comment: @Justme but could it also be that fuse was blown due to some short circuit in the mains? And since the fuse is blown it protected the rest of the circuitry?

Comment: @hacktastical Alright, looking at the pictures especially the second one, is it possible to identify where potentially could be the fuse?

Comment: Why would there be short circuit in the mains? And why would the fuse blown in such case? And yes, it is possible to identify where the fuse is, quite easily.

Comment: @Justme my apologies, I meant when people overload the sockets by plugging in too many devices, it draws significantly large current and the fuse blows. So (maybe) something of this sort might have happened. The reason I said that is components seems to be fine (no black soot) or any electrolyte out of caps. Could you identify the fuse for me please :)

Comment: I can’t tell from the photos where the fuse is. But if the fuse blew, there’s a good chance something else failed too. Proceed with caution.

Comment: The mains input fuse is at the edge of your yellow circle, right below the mains input connector on the PCB (it's usually the first component on PCB where mains come in). Regarding the answer you hastily accepted, I do think that the circled yellow component is just a ferrite toroid and the insulated mains wires just go through it, the heat shrink just prevents it from moving, so it's not shielded because it is live at mains potential.

Comment: @Justme thanks a lot. The fuse was also wrapped in the heat shrink so my eyes got dodged. You have identified it even with a bad viewing angle!  Also thanks for good insight for the purpose of heat shrink, couldnt have figured out on my own! –

Comment: @Justme also I guess the culprit is variable resistors on the top right corner in the second image as they are covered with  some purple color guvy thingy.

Comment: No, that is also there on purpose. The PSU voltages etc are calibrated by adjusting those trimmer values at the factory, and then the setpoint is fixed with the locking compound to prevent vibration from moving the adjusted values during transport and use. I have to ask are you sure that it is the power supply that is broken, instead of the device that is was in, so that you are not destroying a perfectly good power supply?