# Precautionary Discharging Capacitor went Terribly Wrong | SMPS

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, troubleshooting

I wanted to check the fuse of SMPS [pictured](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/502303/troubleshooting-switch-mode-power-supply/502306#502306).

[image]

In order to safely conduct the procedure I followed the discharging procedure as provided in many tutorial videos i.e (connecting the end of the capacitor using nose plier). The fuse seemed alright but I while discharging the capacitor, a loud bang occurred (no power cable was attached)! This was quite loud bang. Does it mean the capacitor is bad? None of the videos warned about such bang! The capacitor was 330 mF.

I cleaned up the soot caused by the bang and checked the capacitance and conductance of the capacitor, I seemed fine, the fuse after rechecking was also fine and pretty much other stuff that I check prior seemed also fine (The power supply is still bad though)

**Question:** Shouldn't the capacitor go bad if a huge bang had occurred followed by soot on the PCB?

Comment: You and I have very different ideas of what “terribly wrong” means.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany It would be quite interesting to know what is your idea for terribly wrong.

Comment: Death, blindness from metal spatter in the eyes, fire that destroys the building, that sort of thing.

Comment: 330 mF seems a bit large a capacitance given the size of the part. Isn;t it 330 µF?

Comment: and it's still not a fuse - you already got that as an answer to your previous question.

Comment: NO reputable videos suggest using pliers or other metal objects to discharge high energy / high voltage capacitors. Any that do are dangerous and poor quality. There is no way of knowing this in advance :-(. Capacitors can be "safely" discharged using a resistor that limits the discharge rate and using insulated wires that prevent shock. You were lucky!. No harm is likely to have been done to the capacitor.

Comment: What part of the “it’s not a fuse”-answer did you not gasp in your other question?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Alright, I know i messed up. This was my first time so I was very cautious and wore nitrile gloves and stuff but somethings are bound to happen no matter what. The good part is I have a disciplinary experience from now on.

Comment: @MarcusMüller "Justme" helped me identify where the fuse is so thats what I checked.

Comment: @winny  Please see my comment above. I was able to locate the fuse with the help of "@Justme"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Shouldn't the capacitor go bad if a huge bang had occurred followed by soot on the PCB?

It appears that you short-circuited high-voltage, high-capacity capacitors. These store a lot of energy and you discharged it all in an instant so you generated a very high current and generated an arc due to poor contact. The soot on the PCB was generated externally to the capacitor. Your capacitor is probably fine.

In future you should discharge the capacitor in a controlled fashion by using a resistor. Work out the power that would be dissipated in the resistor if it was permanently wired across the capacitor while powered. (You could probably use half the calculated wattage for a brief discharge.) Make up some insulated probes attached to the resistor.

Comment: Alright, actually inorder to prevent scruitiny I mentioned that the power supply was off! It was actually on as I first performed HP PSU test which requires power to be supplied on and see blinking of green light. I dont know why but I totally forgot to disconnect and tried to discharge the capacitor while the power was on! (Terrible Mistake) A loud bang with soot. I switched off power, checked the fuse (was fine) and discharged the capacitor again. A smaller bang occurred again! Yet the capacitor and fuse still survived and seemed to be working. Should this be normal?

Comment: I don't know how the fuse survived the first short-circuit. In the second you weren't drawing any current through the fuse. What is a "HP PSU test"?

Comment: I see, maybe the pliers might have not had full contact so probably the capacitor survied. I am quite curios why did it survive. HP test for the PSU is basically removing the PSU from the PC and waiting for some time and connecting the PSU with power (outside the PC) and checking how many time the green light blinks (some diagnostic guidelines). In my case the light doesnt blink at all so I thought the fuse was bad and hence before checking the fuse I took precautionary measure to diffuse the cap! Which went terrible wrong! I am glad I had my gloves on all time.

Comment: You should know, and this has to be mentioned in every instruction manual, that one can't touch high voltage charged capacitors. It's dangerous. Discharging should be done in a safe and controller manner with a transistor, but with a high voltage and high power one. I never did it. But I would take a high impedance, like 1000K and let it discharge for a few minutes. Otherwise you may just blow your resistor.

Comment: @Fredled: Your "with a transistor" remark is a little cryptic. You might want to elaborate in an answer.

Comment: @Transistor Sorry. I meant "resistor". I realized that after I edited it as an answer... LOL.

Answer (score 2):

You should know, and this has to be mentioned in every instruction manual, that one can't touch high voltage charged capacitors. It's dangerous. Discharging should be done in a safe and controller manner with a resistor, but with a high voltage and high power one. Take a high impedance, like 220K and let it discharge for a few seconds or even minutes (be patient). Otherwise you may just blow your resistor.

This is the most simple way to do it. But you must be careful of the resistance value and voltage voltage rating of the resistor.
[Image taken from learningaboutelectronics.com (please read)](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-discharge-a-capacitor)
[image: simple schematic]

[On this page they explain how to build your own discharger](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Constructing+a+Capacitor+Discharge+Tool/2177): It shows the type of resistor you should use.
[and here how to use it](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/How+to+Safely+Discharge+a+Capacitor/75901).
[image: type of resistor]

The value of the resistance advised is different from one site to another. The first site talks about several Mohms, the other about 20K. Several Mohms seems a lot. it depends on the voltage and on the total capacitance. So I took 220K for the schematic but it can be higher.

The power rating of the resistor should be 5W or more.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyFu9T.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this schematic I added a rocker switch to manually control the discharge operation if it has to be done repeatedly. This is optional. The LED  indicator is also optional. The LED on the power supply indicates only the output and may not indicate the charge of the capacitor.

R1, R2 and SW1 should be rated at least as high as the capacitor (600V usually if you are working with 240V AC).
Be aware that the voltage in the capacitor can be higher than 240V even if the input is 240V.

R2 should be lower impedance for lower voltage. R1 can be lower for lower voltage AND smaller capacitance.

Comment: +1 This is great! I am now quite disappointed in videos that illustrate discharging the capacitor using nose plier and without any warnings!